# groovy, ant.fileScanner, fileset, dir - how to use a String variable for the dir parameter in groovy using ant.fileScanner?

Tags: groovy, ant, fileset

I am relatively new in groovy/java, and struggle with a simple task, to process all files following a given pattern in a given directory.

I tried this below, but as soon as try to use a variable instead of a fixed string for the directory of a *fileset*, it tells me that it doesn't find the directory - although it found it when entered as literal string.

My question, how to fix the error in line 34/32?
My code:

```
import groovy.ant.AntBuilder

String hotinfoNumber = new String('5152');
String unzipSpec = new String('*.zip')
String hotinfoDownloadDir = new String('.\\hotinfo_5125')
String[] hotinfoUnzips
hotinfoUnzips = [ '*.zip' , 'H*.zip']

println ('GO, hotinfoNumber=' + hotinfoNumber + ', unzipSpec=' + unzipSpec + ', hotinfoDownloadDir=' + hotinfoDownloadDir + ', hotinfoUnzips=' + hotinfoUnzips)

AntBuilder ant = new AntBuilder();

println 'c+c'
ant.fileScanner {
    fileset(dir: '.\\hotinfo_5152', includes: '*.zip')
}.each { File f ->
    println "c+c - Found file ${f.path}"
}

println ("c+v")
hotinfoUnzips.each { unzipFilespec ->
    println 'c+v-unzipFilespec=' + unzipFilespec
    ant.fileScanner {
        fileset(dir: '.\\hotinfo_5152', includes: unzipFilespec.toString())
    }.each { File f ->
        println "c+v - Found file ${f.path}"
    }
}


println ("v+v")
hotinfoUnzips.each { unzipFilespec ->        // line 32
    println 'v+v-unzipFilespec=' + unzipFilespec
    ant.fileScanner {                        // line 34
        fileset(dir: hotinfoDownloadDir.toString(), includes: unzipSpec.toString())
    }.each { File f ->
        println "v+v - unzips-Found file ${f.path}"
    }
}
```

and the result:

```
c+v - Found file G:\TESTS_SAMPLES\GROOVY\test_misc\hotinfo_5152\HotInfo_5125.zip
c+v-unzipFilespec=H*.zip
c+v - Found file G:\TESTS_SAMPLES\GROOVY\test_misc\hotinfo_5152\HotInfo_5125.zip
v+v
v+v-unzipFilespec=*.zip
Caught: G:\TESTS_SAMPLES\GROOVY\test_misc\hotinfo_5125 does not exist.
G:\TESTS_SAMPLES\GROOVY\test_misc\hotinfo_5125 does not exist.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.types.AbstractFileSet.getDirectoryScanner(AbstractFileSet.java:512)
    at DirAndFile2$_run_closure4.doCall(DirAndFile2.groovy:34)
    at DirAndFile2.run(DirAndFile2.groovy:32)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57397', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any hints and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `new String('string')` or directly `'string'` are equivalent.

The problem in your case is the typo in the `hotinfoDownloadDir` definition.

Note that you change the order of the last two numbers in `new String('.\\hotinfo_5125')` definition compared with the `'.\\hotinfo_5152'`.

`new String('.\\hotinfo_5125')` must be `new String('.\\hotinfo_5152')`, if you change this, your code will work.

Comment: Thanks for this veeery quick response.
But I do not get it. I compared the two code snippets you provided, and in my text editor the look exactly the same. 
Actually, I copied the literal for the directory from the first fileset line 

```fileset(dir: '.\\hotinfo_5152', includes: '*.zip')```

to the line 
```String hotinfoDownloadDir = new String('.\\hotinfo_5125')```

to make sure that they are exactly the same.

Comment: @K.Isbruch the folder name is incorrect in your String variable for the last attempt in your original code, the two last numbers are in different order:52 vs 25